# How to determine big O Time complexity of array difference in Ruby

Tags: ruby, big-o

How do I determine big O Time complexity of array difference in Ruby?

For example:

```
array_1 = [1,2,3]
array_2 = [5,4,3,2,1]

array_2 - array_1 #gives [5,4]
```

How does `array_2 - array_1` work and what is the time complexity of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is how does `array_2 - array_1` work

The Ruby Specification does not prescribe any particular way of implementing `Array#-`. It only prescribes the outcome. Therefore, any Ruby implementor is free to implement `Array#-` however they want, and they are free to change their implementation at any time for any reason.

> and what is the time complexity of it?

The Ruby Specification does not prescribe any particular time complexity for `Array#-`. It only prescribes the outcome. Therefore, any Ruby implementor is free to implement `Array#-` with any time complexity they want, and they are free to change the time complexity at any time for any reason.

It is easy to perform set difference with an expected step complexity of O(n), and it is even possible, but more complex, for certain assumptions about the distribution of values in the sets to do it in sublinear steps, i.e. better than O(n). I would guess most implementors would choose the simpler O(n) solution, but there is no guarantee for that. If you want to know how a specific version of a specific implementation will perform for a specific distribution of elements, then you'll have to look at the source code for that specific version of that specific implementation. But, be aware that there is no guarantee that other implementations or even other versions of the same implementation will do it the same way.

Case in point: Rubinius originally used an implementation of `Hash` that is very similar to the one that YARV uses, but they have since switched to an implementation based on Hash-Array Mapped Tries. So, depending on the version of Rubinius you are using, `Hash`es may be implemented using completely different algorithms. In fact, during a transitional period, Rubinius provided both the old and the new implementation, and you could switch between the two with a command line option.

Just as an example, [here is the current implementation of `Array#-` in Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/array.rb#L387-L396):

```
def -(other)
  other = Rubinius::Type.coerce_to other, Array, :to_ary

  array = []
  im = Rubinius::IdentityMap.from other

  each { |x| array << x unless im.include? x }

  array
end
```

As you can see, the step complexity of `a - b` is Θ(|a| + |b|) for this specific version of Rubinius. But let me reiterate: this is only true for this specific version of Rubinius. Other versions of Rubinius, or other Ruby implementations may (and almost certainly *do*) have different implementations.

Am I right in assuming you are a C++ programmer? The C++ library specification is rather special in that it actually *does* prescribe the complexity of algorithms, and implementors *must* implement the algorithms that those complexities are met. This is not the case in Ruby, and in fact, most other languages.

Answer (score 3):

The naive way to write the method `Array#-` is as follows.

```
class Array
  def -(other)
    each_with_object([]) { |e,a| a << e unless other.include?(e) }
  end
end
```

```
array_1 = [1, 2, 3]
array_2 = [5,4,3,2,1,4]

array_2 - array_1
  #=> [5, 4, 4]
```

The method iterates over each element in `array2` and for each of those elements it iterates over some or all elements of `array_1`. The computational complexity is therefore equal to `O(array_1.size * array_2.size)`.

For larger arrays, we can speed this up by replacing `other.include?(e)` with `other_set.include?(e)`, where `other_set` is the set of unique values in `other`. Sets are implemented with hashes under the covers, so set lookups, like hash key lookups, are very fast, generally regarded as having a computational complexity of `O(1)` (constant time). We therefore might rewrite this method as follows.

```
require 'set'

class Array
  def -(other)
    other_set = other.to_set
    each_with_object([]) { |e,a| a << e unless other.include?(e) }
  end
end
```

```
array_2 - array_1
  #=> [5, 4, 4]
```

This method has a computational complexity of `O(array_1.size + array_2.size)`, where `array_2.size` is the computational complexity of the operation `other_set = array_2.to_set`.

I cannot say this is how Ruby implements `Array#-`, but I am confident it is more-or-less how I've done it, for any method having a smaller computational complexity would not be not be able to examine all the elements in `array_1` or `array_2`, which, obviously, must be done to produce a result.

Note that `other.include?(e)` employs [Array#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) whereas `other_set.include?(e)` employs [Set#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F).

Comment: <pedant mode>time complexity says nothing about how fast an operation is. It describes how runtime _changes_ with varying input size. On small enough inputs, array scans can outperform hash lookups and, say, O(N^2) sorting algo can run faster than an O(NlogN) one.</pedant mode>

Comment: Thanks. You still left the sentence that triggered the comment, but I'll be content with this too :)